# Why isn't the token_pattern parameter in Tfidfvectorizer working with scikit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have this text:

```
data = ['Hi, this is XYZ and XYZABC is $$running']
```

I am using the following tfidfvectorizer:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(
            stop_words='english',
            use_idf=False, 
            norm=None,
            min_df=1,
            tokenizer = tokenize,
            ngram_range=(1, 1),
            token_pattern=u'\w{4,}')
```

I am fitting the data as follows:

```
tdm =vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
```

Now, when I print

```
vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

I get this:

```
[u'hi', u'run', u'thi', u'xyz', u'xyzabc']
```

My question is why am I getting 'hi' and 'xyz' even thought I mentioned that I want it to capture only words that have at least 4 characters? - token_pattern=u'\w{4,}'

Comment: I'm not sure this is it, but I suspect that since you are passing your own tokenizer to the `tokenizer` parameter, whatever you pass to the ngram and token pattern parameters is ignored. Pass `None` to `tokenizer` or handle that in your own tokenize function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to recreate the behavior of the passing a tokenizer function over-rides the `token_pattern` pattern.

Here is a tokenizer that excludes tokens less than 4 characters:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
def tokenizer(x):
    return ( w for w in word_tokenize(x) if len(w) >3)
```

The good news is passing your own tokenizer doesn't override the ngram parameter.

Comment: Great thanks. They should probably add this to the documentation.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#customizing-the-vectorizer-classes

Comment: Thanks @ogrisel I missed looking at this. Thanks for pointing me to this.

Answer (score 0):

token pattern will not work if you are using your own tokenizer, from the [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L319) here.

```
def build_tokenizer(self):
    """Return a function that splits a string into a sequence of tokens"""
    if self.tokenizer is not None:
        return self.tokenizer
    token_pattern = re.compile(self.token_pattern)
    return token_pattern.findall
```